# Is this a good way to create an article in HTML5?

Tags: html, html5

Is this the good way to create a portfolio article in HTML5 or do you have any suggestions?

Not sure about the section but I need it as overlay over the image. Is it better to use a DIV instead?

```
<article class="three columns remove-all project">
   <section class="project-information">
     <header>
       <h4>Ski Trail</h4>
       <time datetime="2010-03-20">20th March, 2010</time>
     </header>

     <p>
       <span class="tag">Graphic</span>
     </p>
   </section>

   <img src="http://placehold.it/291x216" class="img-scale" alt="">
</article>
```

Answer (score 3):

A good reference for element semantics would be [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/). You can read all about the tags and their intended purposes. From their overview for [`<section>`](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#section), [`<article>`](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#article) and [`<div>`](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/#div):

> ## Section
>
> Represents a generic document or application section. In this context, a section is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a header, possibly with a footer. Examples include chapters in a book, the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, contact information.
>
> ## Article
>
> Represents a section of a page that consists of a composition that forms an independent part of a document, page, or site. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a Web log entry, a user-submitted comment, or any other independent item of content.
>
> ## Div
>
> The div element has no special meaning at all. It represents its children. It can be used with the class, lang, and title attributes to mark up semantics common to a group of consecutive elements.

Their analogy of `<section>` is a chapter, an `<article>` is *a section of the page*. Chapters contain articles, not the other way around. A `<div>` might be more appropriate, since it has no meaning.

Answer (score 1):

- You probably don’t want to use a `section` there, as it’s a sectioning content element which creates an entry in the outline. If you need a wrapping element, use `div`.
- The tags would typically be part of a `footer` element of this `article`, unless you’d consider them part of this `article`’s main content.

So it could look like:

```html
<article>
  <div>
    <header>
      <h4>Ski Trail</h4> <!-- you could also use <h1> instead -->
      <time datetime="2010-03-20">20th March, 2010</time>
    </header>

    <footer>
      <span>Graphic</span> <!-- may want to use a <ul> -->
    </footer>
  </div>

  <img src="…" alt="…">
</article>
```

Note that the main content of this `article` (which is a sectioning content element) would be the image, as the content in `header` and `footer` would be considered metadata.